# Implementing a secondary namespace for azure service bus failover

Tags: azureservicebus

I am looking into implementing a failover plan for azure service bus. I've read about Paired namespaces, but I'm not really happy with what that provides, as it doesn't really allow failover to secondary namespace in another data center, just routing of messages to backlog queues during a failover event. To me that isn't going to maintain business continuity as the queue/topic will not be processed during the event.

So, I was trying to come up with another solution, perhaps by duplicating all our messages to a secondary queue/topic, but I can't work out a way of deleting those messages in the secondary queue when the primary message gets completed.

Any ideas, on the best way to achieve this kind of failover with Azure Service Bus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you review ["Best Practices for insulating applications against Service Bus outages and disasters"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-outages-disasters/)? The article describes replication approaches and points to samples and further detail guidance. If that doesn't give you want you are looking for, I'd like to understand what you're looking for so we can look into fixing that.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that before! The sample "Geo-replication with Service Bus Brokered Messages" looks exactly what I want.

Comment: Is there a recommended way to avoid processing a message twice? Also, how do I stop the secondary from filling up if I am not actively reading it. Could I use sessionId so that the the receiver on the primary could get the message from the secondary and delete it?

Comment: I think what I need to do is for my receivers to always check the secondary, though perhaps not as frequently if the primary is known to be up. That will stop the secondary just filling up. Then I can combine that with a write once redis cache to ensure that specific messageIds are not processed twice.

Comment: You can potentially use a carefully chosen TimeToLive for automatic cleanup in the secondary.

Comment: Is using a sessionId that is the same across primary and secondary a reasonable approach to locate a message in the secondary service bus once processed in the primary?

Comment: The message-id certainly is. Session-id is to identify related groups of messages in sessionful queues/topics.

Comment: Is it possible to get a message from a queue/topic by messageId? i.e. process message on primary, locate same message on secondary and complete it.

Comment: No, unfortunately you cannot. We allow receive by SequenceNumber and that only for previously deferred messages.

Comment: Would it work it use the same session id in both buses, where the session just has one message in it. Then use a session client with the session id which would return the one message, i.e. the one we want to complete. Or would this a) not work b) be inadvisable. Thanks for all your help by the way!

Comment: The sessions get served up in the order they sit in the queue, so you still don't get random access. Your session client would simply sit there until competing receivers have pulled the other sessions off and its your session's turn.